# Panel content and script reloaded everytime button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

This is a very simple Firefox addon which:

- adds a `Widget` to addon bar
- attachs a `Panel` to the `Widget`
- the `Panel`'s content contains an `input` element and 2 `button`s

When I click the `Widget`, the `Panel` is shown, as expected.
But when I click `testButton`, `console.log('loaded');` is printed to console.
Why is the `Panel`'s content and scripts reloaded even though I'm not updating the Panel?
Another testcase (with same behaviour), if I enter a value into `inputField` and then click `testButton`, `inputField`'s value is reset to be empty.

Addon code, `main.js`:

```
require("./Panel").init();
```

Module, `Panel.js`:

```
var Panel = require("sdk/panel"),
    Data = require("./Data")
    Widget = require("./Widget");

exports.init = function(){
    ui = Panel.Panel({
        width: 180,
        height: 180,
        contentURL: Data.get("html/Presentation.html"),
        contentScriptFile: Data.get("js/Logic.js"),
        onShow: function() { console.log("showing"); }
    });

    Widget.init(ui);
}
```

Another module, `Widget.js`:

```
var widget = require("sdk/widget"),
    Data = require("./Data");

exports.init = function(panel) {

    widget.Widget({
        id: "test-widget",
        label: "PanelTest",
        contentURL: Data.get("images/ico.png"),
        panel: panel
    });
}
```

Last module, `Data.js`:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

exports.get = function(content) {

    return data.url(content);
}
```

contentURL for panel, `Presentation.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <input id="inputField" type="text" size="10"></input>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="testButton">Test</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="evaluate">evaluate</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

contentScriptFile for panel, `Logic.js`:

```
window.onload=function(){
    console.log('loaded');

    var button = document.getElementById("evaluate");
    button.addEventListener("click", function() { 
        console.log("evaluate clicked");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `type='button'` to your buttons, as this attribute defaults to `'submit'`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), under the `type` attribute:

> > submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! .. `button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.`